# Navigation from one form to another using Alpacajs

Tags: alpacajs

I have one form with one button next. On clicking this next button,it should navigate to other form.

I have created two forms but I am not able to link them.

```
$("#field1").alpaca({
    "schema": {
        "title": "Name Info",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "firstName": {
                "title": "First Name",
                "type": "string"
            },
            "lastName": {
                "title": "Last Name",
                "type": "string"
            }
        }
    },
    "options": {
        "form": {
            "buttons": {
                "next": {
                    "click": function() {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you show us your source code?

Comment: $("#field1").alpaca({
    "schema": {
        "title": "Name Info",
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "firstName": {
                "title": "First Name",
                "type": "string"
            },
            "lastName": {
                "title": "Last Name",
                "type": "string"
            }        
        }
    },
    "options": {
        "form": {
            "buttons": {
                "next": {
                    "click": function() {
                       
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
});

Comment: This is my first form with two fields firstname and lastname. There is one button next. On click of next,it should navigate to other form. I have one query as how to navigate from this form to other form.What I have to write inside this click function so that it navigates to other form

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [Wizards](http://www.alpacajs.org/docs/api/wizards.html), I think that might help you. Tell me If this is not what you're looking for, I'll try to help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I am not looking for Wizard. I simply want one form. If we click on next button,it should navigate to other form but not on different step like wizard. But step same remain same

Answer (score 0):

@smileisbest and @Shabbir-Dhangot, I've implemented two forms in the same page.  Use the JSON library to serialize the data and send to the next form:

```
"click" : function() {
var editJsonData = JSON.stringify(this.getValue(), null, "  ");
doNext(editJsonData);
}
```

Then add the call to the next form as a function:

```
// If JSON data is not null, the next form will display.
var doNext = function(jsonData) {
    $("#NextForm").empty();
    if (null != jsonData) {
        // Validate user or data...
        // This starts the Editor form
        $("#NextForm").alpaca({
"data" : jsonData,
"schema" : {
"type" : "object",
"properties" : { ...
```

Use show/hide appropriately to hide the prior form:

```
$("#field1").hide();
$("#NextForm").show();
```